# How do I show my app in the list of "Share To" targets on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, share

I want my app to appear in the target list when someone selects "Share" from some other app (like Internet Explorer or Pictures).

[image: Share Targets]

How do I do that?

Comment: Never hurts to check [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563(v=vs.105).aspx) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, thanks to @lthibodeaux

Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).